# C# How to handle dynamic events based on Data Change?

Tags: c#, .net, events

So here is a scenario which I am trying to tackle.

Lets say I have a Dictionary which contains string key, and integer value.

I want users to subscribe a specific key when data is changed. How can I do that?

I was thinking of doing it like this.

```
 public class DemoClass : IDisposable
    {
        public Dictionary<string, int> Values = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        public Dictionary<string, EventWrapper> Subs = new Dictionary<string, EventWrapper>();
        public DemoClass()
        {
            Values["A"] = 10;
            Subs["A"] = new EventWrapper();
            Subs["A"].Handler += Handler;
            //Value changed
            Values["A"] = 11;
            //Call Event
            Subs["A"].DoStuff("A");
        }

        private void Handler(string obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            foreach (var keyValuePair in Subs)
            {
                keyValuePair.Value.Handler -= Handler;
            }
            Subs.Clear();
            Values.Clear();
        }
    }

    public class EventWrapper
    {
        public event Action<string> Handler;
        public void DoStuff(string key)
        {
            Handler?.Invoke(key);
        }
    }
```

The above code is tracking all the events for a specific key and when an item is changed it will invoke to all subscribed Users.
Now would this in an efficient way? This works but is there a better way to do it?

Some more context is each subscriber is a User and the data will be 100K in dictionary and lets assume each user will subscribe to many Items in Dictionary.

Comment: Seems to me like you should wrap the value inside your data dictionary with an slightly more sophisticated class than your `EventWrapper` and just have one dictionary (private, not public). But then again, I don't know the specifics of your use-case. You might want to implement an `ObservableDictionary` or some sort instead.

Comment: It looks like someone has implemented an [ObservableDictionary](https://github.com/Cysharp/ObservableCollections/blob/master/src/ObservableCollections/ObservableDictionary.cs).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes seems like a solid implementation too. However I'm not sure an observable dictionary is what the OP is looking for, seems to me like the observation part here is a little less collection observation and more items observations, at least from the code and phrasing of the question.

Comment: Let me give you more context as this will be used on the Blazor Server and each user will be subscribed to a data set on the Backend side so if that specific Data gets changed all users who subscribed to a particular Key will get notified and latest data is given to that user

Comment: ... which changes the game completely!

Comment: Still think you should be exploring the option of storing a private dictionary of string and some class implementing the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-7.0) and only exposing a public `Dictionary<string, int>` as a property (if actually needed) - but then again, this does depends on your specific use-case.